# How to get id of parent from which drag started? jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's take an example we have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".king").draggable();
  $("td").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    $("#target").text($(event.target).attr('id'));
  }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="drop_one"><img src="http://www.houseofchess.com/images/chess_pieces/wooden_staunton/shared/216777-375/nqw.jpg" class="king"></td>
    <td id="drop_two"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="drop_tree"></td>
    <td id="drop_four"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="start"></p>
<p id="target"></p>
```

How can i know id of `td` from which drag started. I know that first started from where i put it, but what when it's moved how to know then from which one `td` drag started. Is there something similar like `event.target` so i can know from which object it started?

Comment: Why not just use `start` to get the id?

Comment: the js draggable has a `start` event. You can do a check on where it is when it starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".king").draggable({
    var this_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#start").text(this_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't need id of element i move, but id of container that element is.

Comment: you are moving the `td` so I am assuming you want that id correct?

Comment: No i'm moving, img

Comment: Thanks that helped i can't belive it was that simple.

Comment: `$(this)` is your best friend